# how can i upgrade only jre from 7 to jre 8 on ubuntu 1404

Tags: jre

I currently have the jre 7 and need to upgrade to 8 on ubuntu 1404. I need only JRE upgraded to 8 for demo purpose. Could you please guide me on this?

```
java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.6) (7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.14.04.1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 7):

OpenJDK 8 for Trusty isn't available  in the official Ubuntu repositories.
As a workaround, you can install OpenJDK 8 from a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~openjdk-r/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).
Open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Or if you only need the JRE

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```

It is usual that several major versions are installed in parallel.

---

To switch between Java 7 and Java 8 use this command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```